# Question on reciprocal metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

First of all, to simplify we will assume 2 dimensional space with a symmetrical metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$

It's known that d'Alembert operator (we will use it for example) is defined as $\partial_\nu \partial^\nu$, where $\partial^\nu=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu$, in flat spacetime we define it as

$$\partial_x^2-\partial_t^2.$$

In general case we have

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix}
 g_t & g_{tx} \\
 g_{tx} & g_x
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So, d'Alembert is

$$\frac{\partial_t^2}{g_t}+\frac{\partial_x^2}{g_x}+2\frac{\partial_t\partial_x}{g_{tx}}.$$

In flat spacetime $g_{tx}=0$, so we have an indeterminate result, how do we deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the components of the dual metric $\tilde g$ are not the reciprocals of the components of the metric $g$.  That is, $\tilde g^{\mu\nu}\neq 1/g_{\mu\nu}.$  Instead, they are the components of the *matrix inverse* of $g$, such that $\tilde g g = g\tilde g = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$.  In two dimensions, we have that

$$\tilde g = \pmatrix{g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{12} & g_{22}}^{-1} = \frac{1}{g_{11} g_{22} - g_{12}^2}\pmatrix{g_{22} & -g_{12} \\ -g_{12} & g_{11}}$$

In the special case that $g$ is diagonal (so $g_{12}=0$), we find that
$$\tilde g \overset{g_{12}=0}\longrightarrow \pmatrix{1/g_{11} & 0 \\ 0& 1/g_{22}}$$

but in general, this is not true.

> In flat spacetime $g_{tx}=0$.

This is not a property of flat spacetime, but rather of an orthogonal basis.  If I start from Cartesian coordinates $(t,x)$ and define new coordinates $(u,v)=(t,x-at)$ for some constant $a$, then
$$\mathrm dt^2 - \mathrm dx^2 = (1-a^2)\mathrm du^2 - \mathrm dv^2 - 2a\mathrm du \mathrm dv \implies g_{uv} = -a$$

This is just a change of coordinates and doesn't affect the curvature of the space; it just means that our basis vectors are no longer orthogonal.

> In the general case we have [...] so the D'Alembert operator is [...]

The general form of the D'Alembert operator is not $g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu$, which you can see by observing that this expression does not transform like a tensor under general coordinate transformations.  The correct generalization is instead

$$\square \varphi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i \big(\sqrt{|g|} \tilde g^{ij}\partial_j \varphi\big)$$
where $|g|=|g_{11}g_{22}-g^2_{12}|$ is the absolute value of the metric determinant.  To see this, we note first that the covariant divergence of a vector field  $V$ is given by

$$\mathrm{div}(V) = \nabla_\mu V^\mu = \partial_\mu V^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\ \ \mu \sigma} V^\sigma \overset{\star}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_\mu \big(\sqrt{|g|} V^\mu\big)$$

where $\star$ is a commonly known identity (which is nevertheless not immediately obvious).  Second, we note that the (vector) gradient of a scalar field is given by

$$\mathrm{grad}(\varphi)^\mu = \tilde g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu \varphi$$

Putting the two expressions together yields the result above, which reduces to the ordinary expression $\tilde g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu \varphi$ when the components of $g$ are constant.

Comment: Thank you, for your quick and nice answer!